# Not able to access cross domain JSON data in IE 10 browser using JQuery $.ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, jsonp, internet-explorer-10

I am trying to read JSON data from different domain/server using JSONP callback method.

Here is the code

```
        $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "http://aaa.bbb.com/?json.wrf=callback",
                crossDomain: true,
                jsonpCallback: 'callback',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "jsonp",
                cache: "false",
                success: function (msg) {
                    alert("success");
                },
                async: false,
                error: function (msg,err) {
                    alert(err);
                }
            });
```

FF and chrome are showing me "success" message but in iE 10 it is showing me "parseerror" i.e it always goes to error section of ajax call.

I am not sure what i am missing, which is not working only in IE.

Should i add anything extra code for IE.? Please suggest

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Learner Added but same "parseerror" is getting populated.

Comment: can you post exact error here

Comment: @Learner error is that it executes error section instead of success section. In error section i am alerting the "alert(err)" which is populating the "parseerror" text.

Comment: is that url return json or something else?

Comment: URL returns JSON wrapped in callback function

Answer (score 0):

Header is needed on your php script
One of these

header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST');

Comment: this is needed if i am using CORS method right.? here i am using JSONP method to access other domain JSON file and its .aspx file